# Error: Could not find or load main class CreatingThread

Tags: java

I have created classes in eclipse under package "first" inside src.
I will execute fine in eclipse. But when I tried to run from the command prompt it will say

> "Error: Could not find or load main class CreatingThread".

But when I copy out same classes into some other folder and remove `package first` it will work fine.
I have set environment variables as below:

```
path %JAVA_HOME%\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin

classpath %JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;.;
```

And these are the classes

```
package first;

public class CreatingThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup());
        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+i);
        }

        MyThread myThread= new MyThread();
        myThread.setName("Child Thread");
        myThread.getThreadGroup();
        myThread.start();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Second class

```
package first;

public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++){
            System.out.println("child thread "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the path leading to CreatingThread.class?

Comment: iin command prompt i did cd workspace\corejava\multithreadingrevision\src\first     then Javac *.java

Comment: You would need to execute with `java -cp . first.CreatingThread`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class `Test.java` e.g. is in `src/test` package than the first line in the class will be something like that `package test;`. You will be able to compile it directly from the `test` folder using `javac Test.java`. But executing should be done with the whole package path from outside the folder - you should execure `java Test` from `src` folder instead of `test`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: after reaching folder where java files exist i executed javac *.java then i hit java CreatingThread --it failed then i tried java first.CreatingThread -- it also failed then  java src.first.CreatingThread --it also failed .But whole show will runs fine when i removed package keyword from the classes then put those classes in any folder and compile ,it will runs fine ..

Comment: Run "java first.CreateThread" from src folder instead "java src.first.CreatingThread"

Comment: Tnq @Mikita Berazouski